# Nginx php5.4 install Phabricator cannot load resource file

Tags: mysql, nginx, phabricator

I am trying to install Phabricator in CentOS.
Nginx + php5.4 + mysql already setup successfully.
But dunno why cannot load all resource files:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://phab.xinliji.me/res/defaultX/phabricator/0b64e988/conpherence.pkg.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://phab.xinliji.me/res/defaultX/phabricator/3010e992/rsrc/externals/javelin/core/init.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://phab.xinliji.me/res/defaultX/phabricator/2291d3b2/core.pkg.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
phab.xinliji.me/:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: JX is not defined
    at phab.xinliji.me/:1
https://phab.xinliji.me/res/defaultX/phabricator/e75e4f9d/core.pkg.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://phab.xinliji.me/res/defaultX/phabricator/0b64e988/conpherence.pkg.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Fixed~ cannot use https to setup it.

Comment: Hi, I've ran into the same issue. How have you resolved it, actually?